# How to use an http endpoint in Swift--more details in body

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, http

New to using API's with iOS development and all. Lets say I have an endpoint:

http://something.com/something/login?email=test@gmail.com&pin=0000&udid=ABCDEFGHIGHL

So the user will input an email address, and PIN, and the device identifier (UDID) will go as well. The response will be saved into memory.

How can I make an HTTP request and save the response basically in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func testCoWS(){
        let url : String = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
        let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            do{

                let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = try  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if (jsonResult != nil) {
                    // process jsonResult
                    print(jsonResult)
                } else {
                    // couldn't load JSON, look at error
                }
            }catch{
            }




        })
    }
```

And of course you will find a lot in Apple documentations : [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/)

Comment: So where would I put the email/password/UDID which would be unique to the user? New to all of this sorry

Comment: You can try this :

`var param = ["email": self.txtmail.text,
        "password":self.txtpassword.text]

    request(.POST, url, parameters: param)`